# Single collection as a result of two Foreign Keys?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

Let's say I have the following entity:

```
public partial class Store
{
    public Store()
    {
        this.ConglomeratesByField1 = new HashSet<Conglomerate>();
        this.ConglomeratesByField2 = new HashSet<Conglomerate>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int ID_Store { get; set; }
    public string StoreName { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ID_Store1")]
    public virtual ICollection<Conglomerate> ConglomeratesByField1 { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ID_Store2")]
    public virtual ICollection<Conglomerate> ConglomeratesByField2 { get; set; }
}
```

With code first, is it possible to have a single "Conglomerates" property that would be the "union" of ConglomeratesByField1 and ConglomeratesByField2, or I have to extend the class with a specialized method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have two different relationships you need two separate navigation properties. You cannot map a single navigation property as the endpoint of more than one relationship.

To get a combined collection you can introduce a (readonly and not mapped) helper property:

```
public IEnumerable<Conglomerate> ConglomeratesByField
{
    get { return ConglomeratesByField1.Union(ConglomeratesByField2); }
}
```